# После клонировании: cannot load module file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, git, github

После клонирования проекта с github получил эту ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
2 modules cannot be loaded. You can remove them from the project (no files will be deleted).  
Xolostyak20. Cannot load module 'file .../Xolostyak20.iml':  
  File .../Xolostyak20.iml does not exist
app. Cannot load module 'file .../app.iml':  
  File .../app.iml does not exist
```

как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нажмите `Remove Selected` и Сделайте `Re-build` - `(Build > Rebuild)` проекта.

У человека которого вы скачали этот репозиторий проект находился в другом месте. И `Android Studio` говорит -  я не могу найти эти файлы.

*Доп. ком. от  **A. Shakhov**: добавить настройки среды `.idea` и личные файлы в `.gitignore` (по умолчанию он скрыт)*

Comment: Так же, на будущее, в `gitignore` нужно занести файлы с расширением `.iml` во избежание таких проблем

Comment: @A.Shakhov да, идея хорошая. Но зачем, если вы просто его выкачали и не планируете больше его загружать? Я просто тоже напоролся на эту проблемы, когда начали вместе с коллегой работать :D

Comment: Благодарю, это помогло

Comment: @A.Shakov добавил ваш комментарий

Comment: @Timur Mukhortov, на маленьких проектах не так заметно, а потом будут трудности, так как в файлах `*.iml` содержатся относительные пути. Да и в любом случае - это хорошая привычка)